# Full Message is not showing in mobile phone using php sms api

Tags: php

Well, I just bought a sms api which is created by php. They provide me this 2 lines:

```
http://fahimit.com/smsapi.php?
user=username&pass=pass&phone=mobile_numer&senderid=sender_name&message=my_message
```

\well now i'm using a html form to send sms. But after message send it's not showing full sender name and message.

For example if i use "Test Sender" as sender_name and "Test message test message" as my_message then it's only showing First word like: Test as sender_name and Test as my_message. I don't understand why it's not showing full message and sender name

**PHP code:**

```
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['Submit'] == "Send SMS")
        {

            $write_numer = $_POST['write_number'];  
            $sender = inputvalid($_POST['sender']);
            $type = inputvalid($_POST['type']);
            $select_msg = inputvalid($_POST['select_msg']);     
            $msg = $_POST['txt'];
            $length = strlen($msg); 
            $err = array();
            $ip =  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            if(isset($write_numer) && isset($sender) && isset($type) && isset($select_msg) && isset($msg))
            {
                if(empty($write_numer) && empty($sender) && empty($type) && empty($select_msg) && empty($msg))
                    $err[] = "All field require";
                else
                {
                    if(empty($write_numer)) 
                        $err[] = "Write your mobile number";
                    elseif(strlen($write_numer) > 13 || strlen($write_numer) < 13)
                        $err[] = "Your mobile number format is not correct";    
                    elseif(!is_numeric($write_numer))
                        $err[] = "Your mobile number format is not correct";    
                    elseif (!preg_match("/^8801(6|5|7|8|9|1)\d{8}/", $write_numer))
                        $err[] = "Invalid mobile number";

                    if(empty($sender))  
                        $err[] = "Select sender name";      

                    if(empty($type))    
                        $err[] = "Select your message type";    

                    if(empty($select_msg) && empty($msg))   
                        $err[] = "Select your message";             

                }
            }

            //error count
            if(!empty($err))
            {
                echo "<div class='error'>"; 
                foreach($err as $er)
                {
                    echo "<font color=red>$er.</font><br/>";                
                }
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<br/>";
            }
            else
            {

                $sms =  "http://fahimit.com/smsapi.php?user=MYUSERNAME&pass=MYPASS&phone=".$write_numer."&senderid=".$sender."&message=".$msg."";       
                $sms = file_get_contents($sms);


                if($sms)
                {
                    echo "<div class='success'>Successfully sent your message to $write_numer. Thank You.</div>";       
                    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO e_sent_sms VALUES('', '', '', '$write_numer', '$msg', '', '', '$length', '$type', '$sender', '$current_date', '$ip' )");
                }
                else
                {
                    mysql_error();
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
        <form name="frm" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>">  
        <table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0"  style="float:left; position:relative;">
        <tr>
            <td>Write Number</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="write_number" placeholder="Write your mobile number" class="td3" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['write_number'])) echo $_POST['write_number']; ?>" /><span style="color:#033;">* Mobile number must start with 8801XXXXXXXXX</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sender</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="sender" placeholder="Sender name" class="td3" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['sender'])) echo $_POST['sender']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message type</td>
            <td>
                <select name="type" class="select">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == "5") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Text</option>
                    <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == "1") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Flash</option>
                    <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == "3") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Arabic</option>
                    <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == "2") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Unicode</option>
                    <option value="6" <?php if(isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == "6") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Unicode Flash</option>
                    <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == "4") echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>Wap Push</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Select message</td>
            <td>
            <select name="select_msg" class="select" id="carDealer">
                <option value="">--Select Message--</option>
                <?php
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT msg FROM e_sms_draft");
                while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                    $draft = inputvalid($res['msg']);
                    $draft = stripslashes($draft);
                    if(isset($_POST['select_msg']) && $_POST['select_msg'] == "$draft")
                    $sel = 'selected = "selecteds"';
                    else
                    $sel = "";

                    echo "<option value='$draft' $sel>$draft</option>";
                }       
                ?>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <td valign="top">Message</td>
            <td><textarea class="textarea2" id="carPark" placeholder="Your message" name="txt" onkeyup="counter(this);"><?php if(isset($_POST['txt'])) echo $_POST['txt']; ?></textarea>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script>
        function putIt(e) {
            $("#carPark").val(e.target.value);
        }

        $("#carDealer").on("change", putIt);
        </script>

            <br/><input type="" name="lbl" style="border:none;"><br/></td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save SMS" class="view"/>
              <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send SMS" class="submit"/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

Can you tell me what's wrong in my code ?

Comment: STRANGE!! WHY SOMEONE PROVIDE NEGATIVE VOTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to urlencode your text before passing it to the URL. Do like this

```
$sender = urlencode($sender);
$msg    = urlencode($msg);

$sms =  "http://fahimit.com/smsapi.php?user=MYUSERNAME&pass=MYPASS&phone=".$write_numer."&senderid=".$sender."&message=".$msg."";
```

Do this for all the variables that you are going to send it to the URL.